# Spring boot cli DependencyResolutionFailedException

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am new to Spring boot and I want to start learning. I have installed Spring boot cli (Spring CLI v1.5.3.RELEASE) and I have created a simple server as below.

```
@RestController
class WebApplication {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    String home() {
        "Hello World!"
    }

}
```

I also set:

```
export proxy="proxy-info"
export https-proxy="proxy-info"
export http-proxy="proxy-info"
```

Set also JAVA_OPTS, still not working:

```
-Dhttp.proxyHost=proxyhostURL
-Dhttp.proxyPort=proxyPortNumber
-Dhttp.proxyUser=someUserName
-Dhttp.proxyPassword=somePassword
```

Started the server:

```
spring run hello.groovy
```

I get the exception:

```
> Resolving dependencies.. startup failed: General error during
> conversion:
> org.eclipse.aether.resolution.DependencyResolutionException: Failed to
> collect dependencies at
> org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:1.5.3.RELEASE
> 
> org.springframework.boot.cli.compiler.grape.DependencyResolutionFailedException:
> org.eclipse.aether.resolution.DependencyResolutionException: Failed to
> collect dependencies at
> org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:1.5.3.RELEASE
>         at org.springframework.boot.cli.compiler.grape.AetherGrapeEngine.resolve(AetherGrapeEngine.java:324)
>         at org.springframework.boot.cli.compiler.grape.AetherGrapeEngine.grab(AetherGrapeEngine.java:129)
>         at groovy.grape.Grape.grab(Grape.java:167)
>         at groovy.grape.GrabAnnotationTransformation.visit(GrabAnnotationTransformation.java:378)
>         at org.codehaus.groovy.transform.ASTTransformationVisitor$3.call(ASTTransformationVisitor.java:321)
>         at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToSourceUnits(CompilationUnit.java:943)
>         at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:605)
>         at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:581)
>         at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:558)
>         at org.springframework.boot.cli.compiler.GroovyCompiler.compile(GroovyCompiler.java:206)
>         at org.springframework.boot.cli.command.run.SpringApplicationRunner.compile(SpringApplicationRunner.java:129)
>         at org.springframework.boot.cli.command.run.SpringApplicationRunner.compileAndRun(SpringApplicationRunner.java:101)
>         at org.springframework.boot.cli.command.run.RunCommand$RunOptionHandler.run(RunCommand.java:111)
>         at org.springframework.boot.cli.command.options.OptionHandler.run(OptionHandler.java:84)
>         at org.springframework.boot.cli.command.OptionParsingCommand.run(OptionParsingCommand.java:54)
>         at org.springframework.boot.cli.command.CommandRunner.run(CommandRunner.java:219)
>         at org.springframework.boot.cli.command.CommandRunner.runAndHandleErrors(CommandRunner.java:171)
>         at org.springframework.boot.cli.SpringCli.main(SpringCli.java:63)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

....

> 1 error
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue when I try to run the sample Hello World program in Spring boot CLI V1.5.4. This is what I did and it started working after that.

```
cmd>set JAVA_OPTS=-Dhttp.proxyHost=<proxyhost.domain.com> -Dhttp.proxyPort=<port>
cmd>spring run app.groovy
```

It worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
cmd>set java_tool_options=-DproxySet=true -DproxyHost=proxy.host -DproxyPort=port
cmd>spring run app.groovy
```

is work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I was also trying the same starter example.
I found that using a newer release was the answer.  Today I just downloaded spring-boot-cli 2.3.3 Release.  When I ran the spring command with this groovy program everything worked fine.  No dependency errors, no complicated fiddling with options or proxy stuff was required.